# How to play a sound sample on every tkinter.text input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-playsound

I need to play a typewriter key sample on every tkinter.text input.
I came across the Playsound module but I don't know how to listen to the inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I've come up with a very similar solution tho its really really laggy. Im basically writing a simple typewriter emulator so the key sound is reproduced for each typed letter.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from playsound import playsound


def key(event):
    key = event.char
    playsound("C:/Users/Isma/key1.mp3")



win = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(win, width=300, height=400)
frame.grid(row=1, column=0)
text = tk.Text(frame)
text.grid(row=0,column=0)
text.bind('<Key>',lambda a : key(a))
image = Image.open("C:/Users/Isma/swintec1.jpg")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
label = tk.Label(frame,image=photo)
label.image = photo
label.grid(row=3,column=0)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Use `playsound("C:/Users/Isma/key1.mp3", block = False)`

Comment: @tgikal Thanks a lot, solved the issue which i was trying to tackle by reducing the sound sample quality and lenght.

Answer (score 1):

You would use a `bind` and setup a function to play the sound when the bind is triggered.

```
import tkinter as tk

def key(event):
    print("pressed", repr(event.char))
    # Play sound here

root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()
text.bind('<Key>', key)

root.mainloop()
```